# Video File save in database OR file(copy to folder website)?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I want to build a  Website that has a number of video files,
What is the best way to do this?
Save Video file in database OR copy in a folder of the website?,
and we would be able to add files later 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends; both methods have their advantages.

File system is easy to work with, it is easy to manually access and manipulate the files and it requires no database and no coding to read and write from the database. Setting up proper access rights to allow uploads of new files can be a bit tricky though, and if there are large amounts of files performance might suffer.

Database requires more coding, and you won't be able to -for example- preview a video file just by double clicking it.

I'd say the scale and ambition of your project, alongside your own knowledge, should decide. If you want to keep it simple, go with file system. Aiming high and know how to do it? -Use a database.

Or start with file system and move to database if and when you feel it is motivated.